# Inserting new row instead of updating

Tags: php, mysql, insert, insert-update

junction table "memberprogram" contains three fields (Memberid  Programid  Option_No).
When i try to update row, instead of updating, it inserts new row.

my code:

```
$query_find = "SELECT * FROM memberprogram WHERE ((Memberid == $Memberid) && (Option_No == 'Option A'))";
$result_query_find = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_find);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result_query_find) == 1)
{
$query_update = "UPDATE memberprogram SET memberprogram.Programid = (SELECT programs.Programid FROM programs WHERE programs.Program_Description = '$Program_Description') WHERE ((memberprogram.Memberid == $Memberid) && (memberprogram.Option_No == 'Option A'))";
        $result_query_update = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_update);
     }
        else {

        $query_insert = "INSERT memberprogram SET memberprogram.Memberid = '$Memberid', memberprogram.Option_No = 'Option A',  memberprogram.Programid = (SELECT programs.Programid FROM programs WHERE programs.Program_Description = '$Program_Description')";
        $result_query_insert = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_insert);
```

}

Comment: Are you sure the `SELECT` query is returning exactly 1 row? If not, I can tell by seeing your code that a row will be inserted.

Comment: yes it returns 1. i have checked it in phpmyadmin

Comment: try with `echo mysqli_num_rows()`

Comment: Is $query_find correct? Try $echo $query_find and execute the result on phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

I don`t believe that your query function in phpmyadmin:

Try this Query:

```
SELECT * FROM memberprogram WHERE ((Memberid = $Memberid) AND (Option_No = 'Option A'));
```

The Equal-Operator should be `=` and not `==`.

And I recommend to use `AND` instead of `&&`.

Comment: And OP's `UPDATE` query also uses `==`, which might be trouble.

Comment: Yeah... I hope he understand that this is generally meaning